# Symfony, Twig how do I find the block to override

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to find the file containing a block and the block to override to make a specific change.

Is there a way to print this information out?

Comment: It's not realy a way to display it but your IDE should be able to find it for you. For example with PHPStorm a simple ctrl+maj+f on your main project folder (or in your Resources if you know it is there) will find the block you want.

Comment: Yes, I marked vendor and the cache directories as 'excluded' because of the noise - but it works. Half the reason I was scratching my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can in 2.7

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-twig-profiler

Look Rendering Call Graph

Comment: That's nice - and the call graph would be exactly what I wanted. On 2.3. for stability but it looks like the answer.